# If x does not occur free in A then (∃x)A→A an absolute theorem schema?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

**My Thoughts:** 
Logically if (∃x)A is false then (∃x)A→A  is true. But if (∃x)A is true. Then A 
must also be true. So it seems this is an absolute theorem schema. 
But how can I give a Hilbert or equational style proof of this?

Comment: That's just existential instantiation, where the fresh symbol never occurs anywhere because $x$ is not free in $A$. Which axioms for $\exists$ does your Hilbert system have?

Comment: But is this statement true or not? I am confused because if I take A = x<4 The left-hand side is true but the right-hand side is just x<4 which may be true or may not be true depending upon the value of x. By this logic, this statement seems false.

Comment: But if you take $A$ to be $x<4$, then your assumption "$x$ does not occur free in $A$" (from the question title) is not satisfied.

Comment: ok. So if x doesn't appear free in A then (∃x)A is the same as A. Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. (And the task here seems to be to prove one direction of that equivalence).

Answer (score 0):

A reasonably short proof of this is that whenever $x$ does not occur free in $Q$, $(\exists x P) \to Q$ is logically equivalent to $\forall x (P \to Q)$.

So in particular, $(\exists x A) \to A$ is equivalent to $\forall x (A \to A)$.

Now $A \to A$ is a tautology, so universally quantifying over it results in a tautology.

Answer (score 0):

There's no contradiction here and I offer an intuitive answer. You misused material conditional connective when you're seemingly logically and thus confidently saying "...then (∃x)A→A is true. But if (∃x)A is true." The previous if/then is a conditional truth functional connective which is true (we say the if/then argument is *valid* in strict English), and the reason why it's true is simply the antecedent is false per material condition definition.